# What is the best approach to segregate composite DTO into multiple domain objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I could not found similar question and I began to doubt whether I was doing it right from the first place whith my domain model.

For example:
We have two domain objects - car and engine

```
class Car {
Long weight;
String model;
String color;
Engine engine;
}

class Engine {
Long power;
Long torque;
Enum fuelType;
}
```

And for the representation level I has a single DTO with all fields without nested objects

```
clas VehicleDTO {
Long carWeight;
String carModel;
String color;
Long enginePower;
Long engineTorque;
Enum fuelType;
}
```

And I cannot decide what the best way to map value from data transfer object to domain model. First approach that came to my mind is to implement mapping in a single service class. But if DTO link to more than 2 domain it will lead to bunch of repositories and other services field injection that looks pretty ugly.

The second solution is to use Chain design pattern where every link is responsible only for field specific to certain domain. But it seems smth not good with the last approach too.

Can you hint please how to solve this issue in a right and neat way?

Comment: Can't you rename the fields as same in any of your classes?

Comment: Why don't you make class VehicleDTO that have CarDTO and EngineDTO inside it (like having DTOs representing the domain objects?